# Using @solana/spl-token-swap package on devnet

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-program

I'm following along with this site https://www.soldev.app/course/token-swap.

However, there seems to be a version difference in the use of TokenSwap.withdrawAllTokenTypesInstruction: I'm using the latest version (0.4.0), but above site is using 0.1.3.

The difference is that the arguments for the withdrawAllTokenTypesInstruction are different, and in my version(0.4.0):

```
static depositAllTokenTypesInstruction(
    tokenSwap: PublicKey,
    authority: PublicKey,
    userTransferAuthority: PublicKey,
    sourceA: PublicKey,
    sourceB: PublicKey,
    intoA: PublicKey,
    intoB: PublicKey,
    poolToken: PublicKey,
    poolAccount: PublicKey,
    mintA: PublicKey,
    mintB: PublicKey,
    swapProgramId: PublicKey,
    tokenProgramIdA: PublicKey,
    tokenProgramIdB: PublicKey,
    poolTokenProgramId: PublicKey,
    poolTokenAmount: bigint,
    maximumTokenA: bigint,
    maximumTokenB: bigint,
  )
```

and my guess is that the argument "poolTokenProgramId" is incorrect, I used TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID(TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA) for that argument, but I am getting an error.

What should I put as the value of poolTokenProgramId?

This is my code

```
const depositIx = TokenSwap.depositAllTokenTypesInstruction(
            tokenSwapStateAccount,
            swapAuthority,
            publicKey,
            kryptATA,
            scroogeATA,
            poolKryptAccount,
            poolScroogeAccount,
            poolMint,
            tokenAccountPool,
            kryptMint,
            ScroogeCoinMint,
            TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,
            token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            poolTokenAmount * 10 ** poolMintInfo.decimals,
            100e9,
            100e9,
        );
```

and this is error code

```
client.js:1 WalletSendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: incorrect program id for instruction
    at StandardWalletAdapter.sendTransaction (adapter.js:205:1)
    at async eval (WalletProviderBase.js:152:1) StandardWalletAdapter {_events: Events, _eventsCount: 4, signTransaction: ƒ, signAllTransactions: ƒ, signMessage: ƒ}
```

Comment: Could you provide more details about the error you’re getting? If it fails at simulation, pass `{skipPreflight = true} ` when sending your tx to be able to view the failed transaction on-chain.

Comment: This is error in console,

Uncaught (in promise) WalletSendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: incorrect program id for instruction

And I modified my code like this, 

`let txid = await sendTransaction(tx, connection, {skipPreflight = true});`

but I couldn't see it on-chain.

Comment: I think your swap program id is incorrect

Comment: Oh thank you!!!!, The above error was resolved by changing the TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID to OLD_TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID, but another error occurred.

`Error: The provided token program does not match the token program expected by the swap`

`custom program error: 0x18`

help me plz :'(

Comment: Oh I Resolved. I put the same `token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID` in mintA and mintB above and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It solved with this code

```
const depositIx = TokenSwap.depositAllTokenTypesInstruction(
    tokenSwapStateAccount,
    swapAuthority,
    publicKey,
    kryptATA,
    scroogeATA,
    poolKryptAccount,
    poolScroogeAccount,
    poolMint,
    tokenAccountPool,
    token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
    token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    OLD_TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID, // SwaPpA9LAaLfeLi3a68M4DjnLqgtticKg6CnyNwgAC8
    token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    poolTokenAmount * 10 ** poolMintInfo.decimals,
    100e9,
    100e9,
);
```